# How to implement Knowledge graph

Tags: nlp, semantic-web, nlp-question-answering, knowledge-graph

I'm looking forward to implement something like google direct answers which uses knowledge graph, is there any useful resource can I read ? also Where can I find data for that?

Answer (score 4):

From the semantic web aspect of your question i guess an interesting starting point for you is the DBpedia ([example queries](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#h28-5)) dataset, maybe in combination with the [strings to Wikipedia concepts dataset](http://googleresearch.blogspot.de/2012/05/from-words-to-concepts-and-back.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am excited for this free class:  [Probabilistic Graphical Models - Daphne Koller, Professor](https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm).  I would look her up and watch her youtube videos in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

The series of free online MOOCs by [Prof. Harald Sack](https://www.linkedin.com/in/harald-sack-88439b5/) are always a great starting point. [Here](https://open.hpi.de/courses/knowledgegraphs2020) is the 2020 course (couldn't find a more recent one) and [there is an upcoming one](https://open.hpi.de/courses/knowledgegraphs2023) starting in Oct'23.